# Selenium is Unable to locate element in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to crawl this website that requires login. I've done the login part (*can be created for free if you wish to test it out). However, when I try to scrape the data from the website it keeps telling me that it was unable to find the element.

Although `<div data-test-id="content-container">` this is what the `<p>` tags under.

My current code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

LOGIN_PAGE = "https://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
ACCOUNT = "Account"
PASSWORD = "Password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys(ACCOUNT)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInPasswordField"))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign in']"))).click()

driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-test-id='content-container']")

text = text_element

for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

and I keep getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@data-test-id='content-container']"}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Try to use `wait` with `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` will be worked!

Comment: where do I use that? @BhavyaParikh

Comment: where your finding that `text_element` with `x_path` also refer it from other post!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Presence means it's in the DOM, not that it's accessible. If you get `.text` on a present but not visible element, you will get an exception. You need to wait for visible instead.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML from the element you are looking for with some of the surrounding elements also so we can check your locator, etc. Have you verified that this element is not in a IFRAME?

Comment: The question includes link to the site, it is more than enough.

Comment: @DSMKSwab Was your question solved/answered?

Answer (score 0):

**1** You are trying to iterate one element. Use **find_elements_by_xpath**

**2** For this case use: `get_attribute("innerHTML")`

```
driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
text_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-test-id='content-container']")

text = text_element

for t in text:
    print(t.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Or, change the locator to `//*[@data-test-id='content-container']/p`:

```
driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
text_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-test-id='content-container']/p")

text = text_element
for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

Complete program would look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

LOGIN_PAGE = "https://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
ACCOUNT = "Account"
PASSWORD = "Password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("LOGIN")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInPasswordField"))).send_keys("PASSWORD")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign in']"))).click()

driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
text_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-test-id='content-container']/p")

text = text_element
for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

Comment: 1 is valid. 2 is not valid, why would you want to get a bunch of HTML that you then have to parse, etc. to get the text from it? `.text` will work just fine. 3 is just going to break the same text up into 20 different pieces instead of one big piece.

Comment: 3) You changed the final locator from "//*[@data-test-id='content-container']" to "//*[@data-test-id='content-container']/p". So if the original one can't be found, why do you think that your locator based off of the original one will be found?